# How can I extract columns from an excel file using a combination of node.js and react.js?

Tags: node.js, excel, express

I was trying to extract the columns from the excel file and display them on the front end but haven't been successful. I don't know if there is a library or something to work with. I have been able to display the sheets that are in the excel file but not successful on displaying the columns names belonging to those sheets

I tried to parse through the first row of the excel file because usally that is where the column names are. I am trying to figure out how to display them before I get to the fact that some tables don't necesarrily have their columns on the first row

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.